# (React Native) Error with npm run ios, build commands failed: PhaseScriptExecution

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-onesignal

I have a very simple project, just a webview and one signal notifications, and when I try to run the app in the simulator, I get the following error:

`The following build commands failed: PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/felipesoares/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appdicadehoje-aopcnwyfxemxetgqwqpniavuytog/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-9AE607B4C5601CAA7EF14079D91A3DE3.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods') (1 failure)`

How can I solve? I think it has to do with one signal or xcode, but I'm not sure

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed your Pods correctly. Also, try to remove `Podfile.lock`, `Pods` folder & clean the build folder. Next, do `pod install` then open your `.xcworkspace` project and build again. I hope this works for you